# UnionAggregate on geometry datatype to fuse geometry

Tags: sql, sql-server, geometry, geospatial

I have a list of geometry fields in a sql table with some other information. I want to fuse the geometry of many rows into one when my query matches a certain id.

I try the UnionAggregate method, but sql server doesn't seems to know what this function is. Also, I don't know if I can fuse geometry that are not connected directly together.

Could you tell me what is wrong with my query and tell me if I can fuse my geometry fields?

My query:

```
SELECT a.fid, b.name, a.geometry::UnionAggregate(a.geom) 
FROM tableA a inner join tableB b on a.fid=b.fid
```

Comment: For clarification, are you using SQL or MySQL??

Comment: I am using the query function in sql server management studio. so I guess MySQL.I am not quite sure.

Comment: it is MS SQL, there is no UnionAggregate in Mysql

Answer (score 0):

Try using it like this:
geography::UnionAggregate()

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me :

```
SELECT
  a.fid, 
  b.name, 
  GEOMETRY::UnionAggregate(a.geom) as 'Ageo'
FROM a 
INNERJOIN b on (a.fid=b.fid) 
GROUP BY
  a.fid, 
  b.name
```